# VSCode duplicate line on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, duplicates

I'll try to explain my best. I use Visual studio code to write javascript code (ES6 / Typescript etc).

When I write this kind of code:

```
import axi[tab] // or enter instead of tab to validate the choice list entry
```

It ends having this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import axi
```

So, I'm not sure what is wrong or what to change about the settings...

Any idea, I know it could come from a plugin somewhere :/

Answer (score 1):

It seems a behavior of an extension. Go to `View > Extensions`, try to disable any of them that seems suspicious and test again.